# Compute $d(n) = [\mathbb{F}_3[a] : \mathbb{F}_3]$ where $a\in K^\times$ has order $n$ and $K$ is a field with $81$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, finite-fields

I know that the group of units $K^\times$ is cyclic of order $80$, so the possible values of $n$, the order of $a$, are $1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,40,80$, the divisors of $80$. Now I am tempted to think that $d(n)=n$ since if $a$ has order $n$, then the $\mathbb{F}_3$-vector space $\mathbb{F}_3[a]$ has basis $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$. Is this correct? I feel like I am missing something.

Notation: $[K:F]$ is the dimension of $K$ as an $F$-vector space

Comment: The element $a=-1$ has multiplicative order two, but is in $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: To put a point on dan_fulea's nice observation, remember that $d(n)$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$. The fact that $a$ has order $n$ means that $a$ is a root of $X^{n}-1$, but that doesn't mean that $X^{n}-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$, only that the minimal polynomial of $a$ *divides* $X^{n}-1$. (In fact, $X^{n}-1$ is never irreducible unless $n = 1$, since $X-1$ is always a divisor of $X^{n}-1$.)

Comment: Because $|K|=81=3^4$ we know that $[K:\Bbb{F}_3]=4$. As $\Bbb{F}_3[a]$ is a subfield of $K$, it follows from the tower law that $[\Bbb{F}_3[a]:\Bbb{F}_3]$ must be a factor of $4$. In other words, $d(n)$ is one of the three alternatives $1,2$ or $4$. Which is it? Hint: $\Bbb{F}_9^*$ is cyclic of order $8$, so if $d(n)=2$, we have _____?